# AssertWasCalled on dynamic in Rhino Mocks

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Is there any way to do an AssertWasCalled on a dynamic in RhinoMocks, like this:

```
    var testObject = MockRepository.GenerateStub<dynamic>();
    testObject.AssertWasCalled(x=>x.MyMethod(Arg<string>.Matches(y=>y == "TestString"));
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible as the GenerateStub<T> where T is a class. Unless you have you have a class that derived from a Dynamic type this might be possible. I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Is there any other way to test if a certain method has been called on a dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, I don't think most proxy based Mock object frameworks 
(RhinoMock/Moq) support dynamic verification.
You may try a profiler based framework such as TypeMock etc, but they are not free.

So the only option I think is to go back to old school where we wrote hand written stubs/mocks.

Create another layer of indirection. A technique in many places describe as extract and override.
So you simply create a hand written mock to verify this behaviour.

a. Create a simple/silly protected virtual member which wraps your dynamic call

System Under Test (SUT) :

```
  public class Sut {
    private dynamic _d;

    public Sut(dynamic d) {
        _d = d;
    }

    public void M() {
        MyMethod();
    }

    protected virtual void MyMethod() {
        _d.MyMethod();
    }
 }
```

b. In your Unit Test, create a testable version of Sut by inheriting from Sut.
Important : It should only contain the overridden method, but nothing else (except the bool to ensure the overridden method was called)

```
public class TestableSutWithDynamic : Sut {
    public bool WasCalled = false;

    protected override void MyMethod() {
        WasCalled = true;
    }
}
```

c. Then simply assert against the testable Sut

```
    [Test]
    public void VerifyMyMethodIsCalled() {
        var sut = new TestableSutWithDynamic();

        sut.M();

        Assert.True(sut.WasCalled);
    }
```